# How to convert List as String from API to List of String

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the following `String` from an API:

```
"[4:00 PM - 5:00 PM, 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM, 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM, 7:00 PM - 8:00 PM, 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 1:00 PM, 1:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 3:00 PM]"
```

I want to convert this `String` to a `List`.
How to convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code :

```
void main() {
  String mylist = "[4:00 PM - 5:00 PM, 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM, 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM, 7:00 PM - 8:00 PM, 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 1:00 PM, 1:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 3:00 PM]";
  
  mylist = mylist.replaceAll('[', '');
  mylist = mylist.replaceAll(']', '');
  List<String> newList = mylist.split(',');
  print(newList[0]);
}
```

Output :

```
4:00 PM - 5:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  String list = "[4:00 PM - 5:00 PM, 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM,"
      " 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM, 7:00 PM - 8:00 PM,"
      " 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM,"
      " 12:00 PM - 1:00 PM, 1:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 3:00 PM]";

  List<String> out = [];

  String batch = "";
  for (String s in list.split("")) {
    if (s == "[" || s == "]") continue;
    if (s == ",") {
      out.add(batch);
      batch = "";
    } else
      batch += s;
  }

  print(out);
}



Output -> [4:00 PM - 5:00 PM,  5:00 PM - 6:00 PM,  6:00 PM - 7:00 PM,  7:00 PM - 8:00 PM,  10:00 AM - 11:00 AM,  11:00 AM - 12:00 PM,  12:00 PM - 1:00 PM,  1:00 PM - 2:00 PM]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

this works

```
String data =
      "[4:00 PM - 5:00 PM, 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM, 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM, 7:00 PM - 8:00 PM, 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 1:00 PM, 1:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 3:00 PM]";

  List<String> dataList = data.replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', '').split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() method in Dart. It will look like this:

```
 void main() {

   String times = "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM, 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM, 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM, 7:00 PM - 8:00 PM, 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 1:00 PM, 1:00 PM - 2:00 PM, 2:00 PM - 3:00 PM"; 

   // Splitting the string 
   // across comma 
   print(times.split(",")); 

   List<String> timesList = times.split(",");
 }


 // Output: 
 //[4:00 PM - 5:00 PM,  5:00 PM - 6:00 PM,  6:00 PM - 7:00 PM,  7:00 PM - 8:00 PM,  10:00 AM - 11:00 AM,  11:00 AM - 12:00 PM,  12:00 PM - 1:00 PM,  1:00 PM - 2:00 PM,  2:00 PM - 3:00 PM]
```